# Google Cloud Datastore index removal

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have few Google Datastore indexes I've added few months. Today I added another one. After few minutes, I found that this is not the right index that I have to create.

I called this:

```
$ gcloud datastore indexes list
---
ancestor: NONE
indexId: XXX1
kind: ThisIsKindName
projectId: GCP-PROJ-ID
properties:
- direction: ASCENDING
  name: QueueName
- direction: ASCENDING
  name: ExecutionLength
state: READY
---
ancestor: NONE
indexId: XXX2
kind: ThisIsKindName
projectId: GCP-PROJ-ID
properties:
- direction: ASCENDING
  name: labels.application
- direction: DESCENDING
  name: ExecutionLength
state: READY
---
...
```

And located the index to be removed (ID=`XXX2`).

I found the [cleanup](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/indexes/cleanup) command description and it's not clear to me. This function is asking to provide `index.yaml` file.

What should be found in this file?

1. List of indexes to be kept. All the indexes that not exists in this file will be removed.
2. List of indexes to be removed.

If your answer is going to be 1 (List of indexes to be kept) - How I can generate a `yaml` file from my existing indexes? Its needed because I don't have those index definitions locally. Needed something like:

```
gcloud datastore indexes list --export=yaml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/indexes/cleanup) the command will remove any indexes that exist that are not included in the index.yaml file. Therefore in the index.yaml file be sure to only include the indexes that you are actively using.

As I am aware, there seems to be no particular means to generate a new index.yaml file, however, it seems that the best course of action would be to attempt to export the output of the command used:

```
    gcloud datastore indexes list > index.yaml
```

(Alter the command to meet your CLI's needs)

And proceed to [format](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig#Datastore_Index_definitions) it appropriately using the provided [example](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig#Datastore_About_index_yaml) as guidance.

Comment: I was worry that this will be the answer. I feel like this is to hard way to go in order to remove an index.. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, I'm glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the properly formatted index.yaml file by using the following script.
https://github.com/ArunMuthuram/gcpDatastoreIndexYamlGenerator
Once the index.yaml is generated, go through and remove the composite indexes that are not required anymore. Use the modified index.yaml in the cleanup command.